# Why does 'Files.exists' return true, but 'File.exists' return false? it occur only when filename in multibyte characters

Tags: java, linux, file, nio, java-io

Why do got this difference?

```
Path docDir

Paths.exists(docDir):true
docDir.toPath().exists():false
```

others attribute:

```
Files.isDirectory(docDir)=true
Files.isExecutable(docDir)=true
Files.isHidden(docDir)=false
Files.isReadable(docDir)=true
Files.isRegularFile(docDir)=false
Files.isSymbolicLink(docDir)=false
Files.isWritable(docDir)=true
Files.notExists(docDir)=false
```

This problem does not occur in single-byte character strings.

Linux version is

```
Linux version 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) )
```

this application is service, and i using the springBoot library.

There is no problem using 'nio' for read/write, but using 'io.File' will result in 'FileNotFoundException'.

Is there anything I've done wrong?

Comment: Is it a symbolic link? What version of Java are you using?  I can't seem find `exists` in `Paths` or `Path` (to `toPath`) for that matter

Comment: FYI: `java.io` doesn't handle symbolic links, where as `java.nio` does (a better job)

Comment: So whats the actual character which has the problem? and also since you are using very old linux, and your name looks like japanese, are you using something like "euc-jp" or "shift-jis" character code? and what's the filesystem are you using?

Comment: Multi-byte characters indicate an encoding problem, so that the actual bytes used when looking for the file is not correct.

Comment: *version 4.4.7 20120313* - time for an upgrade ?

Comment: why not add a `ls` output to see what the directory look like ?

Comment: I assume there is a typo in the question and you mean toFile() rather than toPath(). In that case, you are converting a Path object to a java.io.File which can be problematic. At issue is that Path will retain the file system presentation of the file name (in bytes in this case as it is Linux) but it must be converted to a String for use by java.io.File. It may not decode and encode symmetrically, all depends on your locale/default charset.

Comment: the display of the locale command

`LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

'-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' is specified for the jvm parameter. If you display it with `ls`, that directory will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean

```
    String fileName = "テスト.txt";
    Path docDir = new File ("/tmp/" + fileName).toPath();
    System.out.println(Files.exists(docDir));
    System.out.println(docDir.toFile().exists());
```

then works OK for me @ CentOS release 6.8 (Final)

Although I do remember something like this in a zip file

Comment: That's right, I am sorry. It is not 'toPath' but 'toFile'.
This target is a Japanese name directory and a PDF file.
      docDir.toFile (). exists (): false